# Is it a good idea to maintain open web socket connections between microservices, as opposed to REST calls or gRPC calls?

Tags: microservices

In microservices architecture, components make REST or gRPC etc calls to other components. This involves opening connection, TLS handshake, closing connection.
Is it a good idea to use open web socket connections instead?
Is there any library to do this, for example, in Java?
Bonus question: Is there a library which can in addition, do service discovery and load balancing to the other components? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to use open web socket connections instead?

No.

> Is there a library which can in addition, do service discovery and load balancing to the other components?

Use gRPC with xDS (https://envoycon2020.sched.com/event/ecdJ/xds-support-in-grpc). Which language are you using with gRPC?

Comment: yeah gRPC. even thinking of RSocket.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons of the 'no' ?

Comment: 'No' because all of the features the poster is interested in are available with gRPC natively. And websocket does not offer any advantages - in fact it has connection overheads